# What are the built-in methods for DataFrameGroupBy.transform?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

`DataFrameGroupBy` objects are output by `DataFrame.groupby` and have the method `transform`. According to the interactive documentation (`help(pd.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform)`), this method takes as argument a function that will be applied to each group.

However the [user guide](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation) mentions that strings can also be used as input as a shortcut for "built-in methods":

> Alternatively, the built-in methods could be used to produce the same outputs.
>
> `In [99]: max = ts.groupby(lambda x: x.year).transform('max')`

How can I find the list of strings that will be accepted by `transform`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume it will be the same strings accepted by [`.groupby.aggregate()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) which are (as far as I recall) `['mean', 'median', 'prod', 'sum', 'std', 'var']`.

**EDIT:** While reading the pandas documentation I came across this:

> Here is a quick reference summary table of common functions. Each also takes an optional level parameter which applies only if the object has a hierarchical index.
>   [image]

Taken [from this source](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#descriptive-statistics). It's in the context of using `df.prod()` or `df.quantile()`, but I guess it also translates to the string functions.

Comment: Thanks, but there is still no list on that page. I can trust your list, but ideally I would like to find an official extensive reference... How do we know for instance if a new one has been added to the list?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The only list there is the comparison to numpy functions: ---- The aggregation operations are always performed over an axis, either the
index (default) or the column axis. This behavior is different from
`numpy` aggregation functions (`mean`, `median`, `prod`, `sum`, `std`,
`var`), where the default is to compute the aggregation of the flattened
array, e.g., ``numpy.mean(arr_2d)`` as opposed to ``numpy.mean(arr_2d,
axis=0)``. ---- I can't find more information anywhere.